# Tkinter GUI apparently does not work with Arc… Any other options for GUIs inside of ArcGIS?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, arcgis

I created a python script that validates attributes based on a complex set of While/If/Elif/Else loops. For my purposes, I created a while loop to make sure the target row's attribute was of an acceptable input, and then it follows the matrix after that. If the attribute is not accepted, it is supposed to use Tkinter to create a GUI with the accepted options, then you click one, and it assigns it to that attribute, and continues along down the matrix!!

I was pretty stoked with it, and wrote it all out because I had faith in my coding, and wanted it to work the first time around (how foolish). But the time came to test it, and lo and behold, Tkinter doesn't work within ArcGIS/arcpy... So I was hoping you just could suggest an alternate route to take the following code:

```
def assign(value):
    global x 
    x = value
    mGui.destroy()

def gui3(CONVWGID, a, b, c):
    global mGui
    mGui = Tk()
    mGui.geometry("600x50+500+300")
    mGui.title("Attribute Selection Window")
    labeltext = "Please select one of the following attributes to assign to the selected Convwks feature, CONVWGID: " + str(CONVWGID)

    frame1 = Frame(mGui)
    frame1.pack()

    mLabel = Label(frame1, text = labeltext).grid(row=0, column=0)

    frame2 = Frame(mGui)
    frame2.pack()

    mButton = Button(frame2, text = a, command = lambda: assign(a)).grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10)
    mButton = Button(frame2, text = b, command = lambda: assign(b)).grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10)
    mButton = Button(frame2, text = c, command = lambda: assign(c)).grid(row=0, column=2, padx=10)

    mGui.Mainloop()     #FOR WINDOWS ONLY
```

I was thinking of doing a raw_input() command instead of the GUI, but I really like how the GUI looks and operates... Do you have any suggestions?

What I think is happening is that it's just kind of skipping the call to my Tkinter gui3() function, which skips the assign() function.Then right after those are called, I assign the global variable 'x' to the attribute, but since x hasn't been defined, it just stops. Screenshot: imgur.com/psLlnUD

I'm ultimately getting a "NameError: global name 'x' is not defined." error

Here is the first step in the actual decision matrix:

```
for row in ucursor:
    while row[0] != "X" or row[0] != "Y" or row[0] != "Z":
        gui3(row[8], "X", "Y", "Z")
        row[0] = x
    if row[0] == "X":
        ...
```

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? Does it cause the program to crash? "global name 'x' is not defined" seems pretty self-explanatory. Do you understand what that message means?

Comment: `mLabel = Label(frame1, text = labeltext).grid(row=0, column=0)` is a bad idea, because grid method returns None.

Comment: @BryanOakley It's not initiating any gui for me to select from, which then causes the NameError since x has not been assigned a value..

Comment: If it's not creating the GUI, you should either be getting an error (other than the "x not defined" error, or you should see a window. If neither of those are the case, perhaps your logic is incorrect and none of the expressions are returning True. Have you put print statements in your logic to verify you're in a block of code that calls `gui3`?

Comment: @EricLevieil: in this case it's moot, since the code never uses `mLabel` anywhere else. But you are right, it's a bad practice that should be avoided.

Comment: In my view, if `mLabel` is never used, it should not be defined.  Dittlo for mButton. Code checker (lint) programs will flag names like this.

Comment: If one closes the gui (or it closes by itself) without x being assign, you should expect that error message.  Post the entire traceback if you want more help with interpreting the message.  Just today there was another SO question or two where people has problems with uninitalized globals.  There is a reason that many experienced programmers recommend against variable globals.

Comment: I can think of two possible reasons that ArcGIS and tkinter interfere with each other: both run event loops; you use 'import *' with both and there is overlap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As soon as I tried to run your code, the answer popped up in the traceback:
`AttributeError: '_tkinter.tkapp' object has no attribute 'Mainloop'`
The uncaught exception in gui3 kills the code that calls it and `row[0] = x` is never executed, even though the gui remains displayed and even though assign might be called.  With 'M' lowercased, (and index 8 changed to 1)

```
for row in (('A', 1), ('X', 2), ('b', 3)):
    if row[0] not in {"X", "Y", "Z"}:
        gui3(row[1], "X", "Y", "Z")
        print( x)
```

works fine.

Having the window disappear and reappear was visually annoying to me.  I personally would put up a window -- 'Verifying data' (with line numbers rolling up -- and change the content when action is needed.

Comment: I don't know how it got messed up, but when I brought the code from it's own .py script to my tool script, those 'M's got uppercased, and that is what was throwing it off I suppose. That was a really simple fix, but one that I wouldn't have caught until I pulled out all my hair and re-wrote it from scratch. Thanks a lot for pointing that out to me @Terry Jan Reedy!!

Answer (score 0):

You can create GUI windows in wxPython that run inside ArcMap and interact with the map document, but you need to put them into an ArcMap Extension which loads when ArcMap starts.  This needs to create an wx.App object ONCE when the extension loads and then you can make one or more action buttons, tools, or other components on a toolbar inside the extension. Any GUI windows that are opened by wxPython need to be hidden using wx.Show(False) and NOT closed using wx.Close() or wx.Destroy.  I have a post on this forum about it on StackOverflow:

[Repeated calls to ArcMap Python Add-In with wxPython fail after one successful call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49887825/repeated-calls-to-arcmap-python-add-in-with-wxpython-fail-after-one-successful-c)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/50377929/8766731

There is a good video on how to do this on the ESRI website:

https://www.esri.com/videos/watch?videoid=1229&isLegacy=true

This shows how to build the ArcMap Extension, a Toolbar in the Extension, and a Tool on the Toolbar.  In my case, I put an action Button on the Toolbar instead of a Tool, but the same approach works.